Call XARecoveryModule in JBoss bean to add customized XAResourceRecoveryHelper
JBoss 7.0. Data Source already configured in standalone xml.
I would like to create the new object implementing com.arjuna.ats.jts.recovery.XaResourceRecoveryHelper with overrided method:
public XAResource[] getXAResources() throws Exception;

to avoid logging javax.resource.ResourceException all the time in some instances during tests.
but I have problem to call implementation of org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecovery to get object implementing com.arjuna.ats.jts.recovery.XaResourceRecoveryHelper (similar to ex. com.arjuna.ats.internal.jbossatx.jta.XaResourceRecoveryHelperWarapper).
I have not any arjuna dependency in pom, mentioned above classes are copied from stack trace only.
How to create and register new XaResourceRecoveryHelper implementation programatically?

The Narayana documentation (especially, the "Failure Recovery" chapter) can help you with your goal. Moreover, Ondra wrote a great blog about Narayana periodic recovery of XA transactions. I hope these resources will be helpful :-)

OK. I've got modules from com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.common.recoveryPropertyManager,getRecoveryEnvironmentBean().getRecoveryModules() and than got proper XaResourceRecoveryHelper instance via reflection FieldUtil but... received from mentioned above helper / wrapper XAResourceRecoveryImpl object (with all credentials etc.) is not castable in my customized XaResourceRecoveryHelperCustom constructor, although for compilation I have in pom the same version of jar as found in the jboss module directory. Why? How could I get it in JBoss 7.0?

The XaResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper is '.internal.' and is not intended to be customized in JBoss.
If this is only for a testing purpose, what about changing the logging level for certain packages instead?

OK. I've  deregistered problematic XAResourceRecoveryHelper instance and logs have not not apear anymore. This XAResourceRecoveryHelper is useless for testers, because they they don't need the data source it connects to.
